# Save full html page sourcecode in a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I search the best way to save a source code from a html page in a Javascript variable.
The html source code is loaded with php & mysql and looks like for example this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Images</h2>
<p>HTML images are defined with the img tag:</p>

<img src="w3schools.jpg" alt="W3" width="104" height="142">

</body>
</html>
```

If I try to simple save it to a variable

```
var html        = "<?php echo $my_html; ?>";
```

I get different errors. For example `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`. I think the reason is that there are quotation marks, line breaks, special chars and so in the the content of `$my_html`. Of course I can save the html content before to an invisible textarea and take then the content of the textarea to the variable. But is there no other / better way?

Comment: Did you try escaping the string?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the JavaScript variable independently. `document.documentElement.outerHTML;` is a reference to the HTML contents.

```js
var markup = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
console.log(markup)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Images</h2>
<p>HTML images are defined with the img tag:</p>

<img src="w3schools.jpg" alt="W3" width="104" height="142">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, how you mean this? My my page source code comes from mysql to a php variable. And is not the same like the page source code.

Comment: I don’t understand what you are asking then.  Where is the source loaded on the client side?  It has to be returned somewhere already.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are working with PHP, I would recommend using a native function prior to setting the JS variable.
Have you tried [addslashes()?](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_addslashes.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <?php 
    $str = addslashes('What does "yolo" mean?');
    echo($str); 
  ?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't work then I get back "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token".